# AngularJS 'исполнение' контроллера после выполнения $http

Tags: angularjs, сервер, http, controller

```
angular
    .module('lessonApp')
    .controller('taskCtrl',taskCtrl);

function taskCtrl($http, $scope) {
//загрузка первоначальных данных
    getTaskJson.getJson()
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.json=response;
            });
...
//много разного которое должно работать после получения $scope.json
}
```

1. Как сделать, чтобы все что внутри контроллера taskCtrl, исполнялось после получения данных от `$http сервиса(getTaskJson.getJson())`. Пихать все в `then`? Наверное оч.плохая идея.

Comment: `ng-route` или `ui-router` используются?

Comment: в данном случае да, но есть другие где не используется

Comment: если используются - то лучше всего использовать `resolve`, если нет - `then` вполне хорошее решение

Comment: `ng-init` вообще не для этого и рекомендация по его использованию **только** как алиас для переменных в ng-repeat

Comment: Стоит определиться - о чем все-таки вопрос: как получить переменную? или что?

Comment: Тогда второй вопрос удаляю

Comment: Тогда можешь смотреть комментарий выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня есть пример с resolve [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/36FsCrJAgk43s4Saj7Ym?p=info)

```
// ui-router config
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
        .module('plunker')
        .config(config);
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];
/* @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
                .state('directive', {
                    url: '/directive',
                    templateUrl: 'directive.client.view.html',
                    controller: 'DirectiveController',
                    controllerAs: 'directive',
                    resolve: {
                        getButtonsService: getButtonsService
                    }

                });
    }
    getButtonsService.$inject = ['buttonService'];
    function getButtonsService(buttonService) {
        return buttonService.getButtons().then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    }
})();
```

Там же есть контроллер и сервис, получающий данные с json.

Документация ng-route по resolve [тут](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Документация ui-router по resolve [тут](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: пример так же есть в справке для обоих роутов

Comment: Практически всё есть вообще в документации

Comment: Поэтому стоило бы добавить ссылки на нее :)

Comment: Почему тогда в вашем комментарии не добавили?)))

Comment: Потому что лень искать это раз :) и два, ссылки(важные для ответа) все равно лучше переносить из комментариев в ответ

Comment: Согласен. Я добавил в свой ответ

Comment: для обычного [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when)